# How to understand if a wall crack is serious?

Tags: drywall, walls, crack, interior, cracks

I am trying to determine how serious this wall crack is. I am open to all comments and suggestions. In particular, I was wondering:

1. How to assess the damage? Should I get professional help, if so, what kind of engineer/repair person should I contact?
2. How to tell if it is only aesthetic? Or if it is a structural problem?

Thank you!

[image: a maybe serious maybe not cracked wall]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is where two drywall join, so not serious, just cosmetic.

It looks bad, but it is just the drywall joint tape coming off.

Easy fix with some drywall joint tape and some compound and paint over.